# Remapping keys when connecting Windows keyboard to Macbook pro

Tags: mac, keyboard, macbook, keyboard-layout

I recently connected my Windows keyboard to my MacBook Pro. The keyboard has a Croatian layout and I have picked "Croatian - PC" as the input language in keyboard settings.
Everything mostly works fine, except for one problem. On my Windows keyboard, I would usually use Alt Gr + some key to produce a specific character. For example:

- Alt Gr + V would produce @
- Alt Gr + F would produce [
- Alt Gr + G would produce ]

But now when I connected my keyboard to MacBook pro, those combinations no longer work. For example:

- Alt Gr + V produces √
- Alt Gr + F produces ƒ
- Alt Gr + G produces ©

My question is: how can I remap those key combinations so that they're exactly the same like they were on Windows?

Alternatively, how can I find a map of the current layout to learn the new combinations? I currently don't know how to produce the @ key with my keyboard, for example, and I have to rely on copy/pasting it from the web.

Answer (score 0):

Mac doesn't differentiate between actually pressing Ctrl+Alt & pressing AltGr. They're in effect 'the same key'.

You *might* be able to get something like [Karabiner](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/) to differentiate, but I've never used it.

You can manually search for which keys would produce @ by opening the Keyboard Viewer - from the menu bar if it's shown, or enable it in System Prefs > Keyboard > Keyboard.
Holding combinations of modifiers will show you what is mapped to where.

Comment: Interesting, when I use Ctrl + Alt + V it does not produce the √ character like the Alt Gr + V does. Perhaps this is because I have picked "Croatian - PC" and not "Croatian" as the input language? In any case, Keyboard viewer works good, but I'll have to learn the key combinations. Unfortunately, Karabiner doesn't allow me to add custom complex modifications, but only simple ones, while complex ones have to be downloaded from the internet and I don't think any of them suits my needs.

Comment: hmmm... Your three AltGr examples on my keyboard are actually the same as if I just press alt+letter - if I add Ctrl then actually no [visible] characters are produced at all, though something is there as the cursor doesn't move back until I backspace the same number of presses.

Comment: Same thins happens to me, although I didn't realize that invisible characters are produced if I additionaly press Ctrl (I just thought nothing at all happens)